# Undo Gerrit push on GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, git-reflog

I've accidentally done a Gerrit style push on a GitLab repo.

That is, while on my local branch I did:

```
$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 3.06 KiB | 184.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To gitlab.domain-name.com:project-name.git
 * [new reference]   HEAD -> refs/for/master
```

When what I should have done was a simple:

```
$ git push -u origin branch-name
```

This reference does not show anywhere on the GitLab web GUI as far as I can tell.

How can I undo this? Do I need to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the reference on the remote with the following command:

```
git push -d origin refs/for/master
```

---

*Full demo:*

```
$ git ls-remote
From git@gitlab.domain.tld:repository.git
9379c44dc1925987c6d2ebdd62e2c91435cf3c8a    HEAD
9379c44dc1925987c6d2ebdd62e2c91435cf3c8a    refs/heads/master

$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 286 bytes | 286.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To gitlab.domain.tld:repository.git
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> refs/for/master

$ git ls-remote
From git@gitlab.domain.tld:repository.git
9379c44dc1925987c6d2ebdd62e2c91435cf3c8a    HEAD
a5b0640960e5a1f26e784d2f93f94f0ec29d5f51    refs/for/master
9379c44dc1925987c6d2ebdd62e2c91435cf3c8a    refs/heads/master

$ git push -d origin refs/for/master
To git@gitlab.domain.tld:repository.git
 - [deleted]         refs/for/master

$ git ls-remote
From git@gitlab.domain.tld:repository.git
9379c44dc1925987c6d2ebdd62e2c91435cf3c8a    HEAD
9379c44dc1925987c6d2ebdd62e2c91435cf3c8a    refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 1):

Git refspec uses two refs ([source](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec))

- `refs/heads` to track local branches.
- `refs/remotes/` to track remote branches.

`refs/for/` is a Gerrit specific namespace and so should not affect your repo since you are not using a Gerrit server. ([source](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/concept-refs-for-namespace.html))

Comment: This is great contextual info in addition to the method in @Matt's answer, thanks Amit!